# Error to install Oracle JDeveloper

Tags: windows, jdeveloper

I install JDeveloper in Windows and have one error..

> El archivo log del iniciador es C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2016-10-21_10-24-28AM\launcher2016-10-21_10-24-28AM.log.
>   Extrayendo instalador... . Listo
>   Fallo en la autoextracción en C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Temp\sfxBE26.tmp.
>   El log está ubicado aquí: C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2016-10-21_10-24-28AM\launcher2016-10-21_10-24-28AM.log.

Anyone know what can it be?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the two files that are on the download page in the same directory. The exe file and the zip file.

Comment: Hi Shay,
mine both(exe and zip extract) are in the same folder, but also same error. Tried doing diff things but did not work out, is there any other solution.

Comment: The zip file should not be extracted - keep the original zip file in the same directory as the exe.

Comment: Great, it worked. For this small mistake, I wasted my day digging and thinking more, I even uninstalled antivirus too.

Answer (score 1):

Your question's answer is as follows:

1. There are two files in your JDeveloper Studio Download, right?
2. You place them (both) in a directory, so that they can be together in the same path folder you placed for them.
3. Okay, now when you execute that .exe that weights 2GB, it displays a console telling you the log you showed.

***Solution:***
In the path log it indicates you, it tells you that the name of the .zip contained must have the same exact name that it displays to you.

[image: Image of the log]

In my case was  V998593-01-2, because before that, the .zip file was named as V998593-4 so I just changed the name to the .zip file and then execute as an administrator the .exe file Voala! It's ready!.

Thanks for your attention, if you have any issues with this solution, do not hesitate to follow this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Download both File1 and File2 and place them in the same directory. Don't ever unzip any file. Just double click the *.exe file and it will work.

Comment: It's required to have the two files indicate in the Oracle's page into the same directory.

In my case, it was necesary to run as admin the .exe file (with the unzip file at side).